# Change CGContextSetLineWidth with uislider

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider

I am trying to change a line stroke with `UISlider`, but it doesn't work. The slider value is okay but nothing is changed.
The slider is on the display and runs and give a value back on a label. I think the function is drawed on the first load and than it stops. But i don't know how fix that problem.

My `.h` file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Draw : UIView {
    IBOutlet UISlider *slider;
    IBOutlet UILabel *label;
}

- (IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(id)sender;

@end
```

My `.m` file:

```
#import "Draw.h"

@implementation Draw


- (IBAction) sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender {
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", slider.value];
    NSLog(@"slider value = %f", sender.value);

}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {




    }
    return self;
}



- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect;
{

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 50.0, 50.0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 250.0, 100.0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 250.0, 350.0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 50.0, 350.0);
    CGContextClosePath(context);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, slider.value );
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

In your method `- (IBAction) sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender` you should call `[self setNeedsDisplay]` to inform the view that the contents need to be redrawn.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the UI that it needs to be redrawn with the `-[UIView setNeedsDisplay]` message. Otherwise, it doesn't know that anything related to how the view is drawn has changed

```
- (IBAction) sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender {
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", slider.value];
    NSLog(@"slider value = %f", sender.value);
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```